# Word with meaning of "taking advantage of somebody"

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I need one word with the meaning of "take advantage of somebody for personal benefit", is there any one?

Comment: Apparently [snooker](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/snooker) has not been suggested.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best word would be *[exploit](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/exploit)*.

Answer (score 1):

As another poster said, the best answer no doubt is "exploited".                         Your ignorance (of a particular situation) may be taken advantage of, (exploited) by someone who is deceitful, or dishonest, etc. and obviously has a perverse character to treat someone unfairly in order to get some benefit for himself. The perpetrator may be a boss, a so-called friend, an older (and much bigger & stronger) sibling, a bully, a coworker, etc.

Comment: Also, to describe feeling taken advantage of, consider the term "be put upon". When your kindness and sincere friendship is mistaken for weakness, and/or gullibility, and/or stupidity especially on a regular basis you feel <put upon>. To use (someone) or to manipulate him to one's advantage is absolutely disgusting. Unbeknownst to you that so-called "friend" is ostensibly returning friendship but his actual (and concealed) purpose is to USE you (exploiting your ignorance, or BE PUT UPON) to elevate himself, his ego, his place on top of the stupid artificial social hierarchical order. Toxic!

Answer (score 0):

*Victimize* might work well in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Bamboozle might be used to mean this.

Comment: "Bamboozle" is much more closely associated with the act of confusing someone. This might be part of the process of taking advantage of them, but it's not central to the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: to [deceive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deceive) ?

> to mislead or falsely persuade others;
>   practice deceit: an engaging manner
>   that easily deceives.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best one is SWINDLE. (especially when you deceive him/her to get money).

Comment: Welcome on [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com). Thank you for your answer, but you may improve it by adding [reference](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swindle).