# Word for feeling of being used by someone

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Word with meaning of “taking advantage of somebody”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/word-with-meaning-of-taking-advantage-of-somebody)

Is there a word for the feeling of being used by someone? For example,

> Person X used Person Y for monetary gains.
>
> Person X after being in love with Person Y, felt used when he/she left him.

Comment: "Exploited" would be a good choice.

Comment: Related: _[Word with meaning of “taking advantage of somebody”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/24933/5822)_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A stronger word than used is **exploited.**

Comment: @drɱ65δ: Thanks. IYHO is worth a great deal to me (emphasis on Y).

Answer (score 1):

You could use **manipulated** or in some cases (depending on context) **victimized**.

Comment: Manipulated and victimized are synonyms for used, not words for the *feeling* of being used. You'd still have to say you "felt manipulated" or "felt victimized".

Comment: Person X manipulated Person Y for monetary gains.

Person X after being in love with Person Y, felt victimized when he/she left him.

Answer (score 1):

One may feel being **taken for granted**.

> "Things change. He starts leaving the dishes in the sink. You do them. You like doing things for him, at first. But then one day you realise you are doing rather a lot for him and he isn’t doing much in return. You are being taken for granted."  - [*source*](http://bookofdistraction.blogspot.com/2011/08/10-signs-that-you-are-taken-for-granted.html)

A more detailed explanation:

> Here is an example. You hire somebody to do something for you; he does a very good job and he is very proud of his work, but you do nothing to thank him and treat his work as if it was nothing. You did not care about his effort he put into it, and he is insulted. Another example is going to an orphanage and donating toys to children, but the children just take them and throw them in a pile with the rest of their toys; the toys you bought meant nothing to them. In either case, you were taken for granted.
>
> Here is another example. You see a loaf of bread on the table and you have the attitude of "so what?" and don't think anything special about it. However, your grandmother spent six hours to bake that loaf of bread and you treat the bread like any other ordinary bread you buy at the supermarket. Your grandmother would get very mad at you because you took her bread for granted.
>
> **To take people for granted means to show no consideration for the efforts of what they have done for you.** In short, you do not care. Everybody has taken something for granted in their lifetimes. Suppose you got tired on an airplane and you need a pillow to rest on. You rudely tell the stewardess that you need a pillow and she looks all over the plane for one, but the only thing she can find is her own pillow in the back; she gives you her own pillow and you don't even thank her. She would be very mad at you because you took her for granted.
>
> [*forum.wordreference.com*](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1452590&langid=18)

Answer (score 1):

My own choice would be 'put upon'.